# Is true or false that there is $X$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology such that $X$ countable with more than two points and connected

Tags: general-topology

Is true or false that there is $X$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology such that $X$ is countable with more than two points and connected?

I really have some intuition that it is false, but I can't find any proof.

Comment: If Im not wrong the subspace topology of X is discrete.

Comment: @Masacroso, I thought about this, but, I have no conclusion.

Comment: Someone here leaves a very good comment (sadly it was deleted) remembering to me that $\Bbb Q$ is not discrete as a subspace of the reals. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $X$ is countable, then so are its projections onto the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: ok, and then it can not be connected, once the subspaces that intercept $x$ and $y$ axes are countable and, if I am not wrong, can't happen such type of connectness on $\mathbb{R}$, once every connected is an interval?

Comment: The particular property you need is just that if $U\subset \Bbb R$ is countable and $a, b\in U$ with $a\ne b$, then there is a $c \in (a,b)$ with $c \ne U$. Apply that ot a projection of $X$, and ask, what is the inverse of $c$ under that projection?

Comment: I don't know if I am very clear with your statement, but here goes my "proof" based on what you have said: Suppose that there is such $X$. The projection functions are continuous, then, $\pi_x(X),$ $\pi_y(X)$ are conncted. But then $\pi_x(X)$ is one interval, that is uncountable, what gives a contradiction.

Comment: Well done. That is a cleaner proof than I was pointing at, though it does depend on already knowing that connected sets of real numbers are uncountable. Note though that $\pi_x(X)$ could be a single point, in which case you need to use that $\pi_y(X)$ is uncountable. If both are a single point, then $X$ would be as well. My own idea was that $\pi^{-1}(c)$ is a line not intersecting $X$, and dividing it into two pieces, as per Arthur's approach.

Comment: nice! I realized the two carreful things I have to take and I enjoy and appreciate your solution! Thanks a lot! I really liked!

Answer (score 2):

You might use this idea: the set of lines in the plane is uncountable, so there must be a line that does not intersect $X$. That line divides the plane into two halves, and $X$ intersected with each of those halves is both closed and open in $X$.

This needs some tweaking to make sure that both halves intersects non-empty with $X$, but that is not too hard.

Comment: I really enjoyed such idea, I will keep this in my mind for future proofs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb R$ is a countable subspace.

Choose your favourite points $a,b \in A$.

The set $\{d(a,c) \colon c \in X\}$ is countable

So we can choose some $ r \in (0,d(a,b)) $ such that no $d(a,c)=x$.

Then $A$ is separate by the open sets $U = \{x \in X \colon d(a,x)<r\}$ and $V = \{x \in X \colon d(a,x)>r\}$

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks!